# Android Toast doesn't show

Tags: android, tcpclient, toast

I have an application that get user input(name and number) , then scanning QR code , and on a press of a button it send the data to my server and get replay from it.
everything is working now as it should.(I can see the message for the server as string when I'm in debug mode).

but I can't see the toast - it doesn't shown
why?

this is the class I have in the ScanActivity.java

```
public class ScannedBarcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


SurfaceView surfaceView;
TextView txtBarcodeValue;
private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
private CameraSource cameraSource;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 201;
Button btnAction;
String intentData = "";

String  ServerReply;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_barcode);

    initViews();
}


private void initViews() {
    txtBarcodeValue = findViewById(R.id.txtBarcodeValue);
    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    btnAction = findViewById(R.id.btnAction);

      btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (intentData.length() > 0) {

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try  {

                            String server_ip = "My.Server.Public.IP";
                            int server_port = 9999;

                            String messageStr = intentData + "!" +  phone +"!"+ name+"!##";



                            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(server_ip, server_port);



                            PrintWriter mBufferOut = new PrintWriter((new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()))), true);
                            BufferedReader mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                            mBufferOut.println(messageStr);
                            ServerReply = mBufferIn.readLine();
                            mBufferIn.close();



      //see why this is not working - can;t see the toast
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside the thread",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            clientSocket.close();


                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
             //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ServerReply,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                thread.start();


                }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ServerReply,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SystemClock.sleep(1000); //ms
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Going to Main Page now",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();



        }


       // }
    });
}
```

this is the how it's look after what you told me to do :(still doesn't work , and for some reason it "skip" the toast part)

```
public class ScannedBarcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


SurfaceView surfaceView;
TextView txtBarcodeValue;
private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
private CameraSource cameraSource;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 201;
Button btnAction;
String intentData = "";
boolean isEmail = false;

String  ServerReply;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_barcode);

    initViews();
}


private void initViews() {
    txtBarcodeValue = findViewById(R.id.txtBarcodeValue);
    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    btnAction = findViewById(R.id.btnAction);

 ;


    btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (intentData.length() > 0) {

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try  {

                            String server_ip = "My.Server.IP";
                            int server_port = 9999;

                            String messageStr = intentData + "!" +  phone +"!"+ name+"!##";

                            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(server_ip, server_port);

                            PrintWriter mBufferOut = new PrintWriter((new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()))), true);
                            BufferedReader mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                            mBufferOut.println(messageStr);

                            ServerReply = mBufferIn.readLine();
                            mBufferIn.close();

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside the thread",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                            clientSocket.close();


                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                thread.start();



                }


            SystemClock.sleep(1000); //ms

            finish();



        }


       // }
    });
}
```

Comment: you have to show toast on UI thread.

Comment: are you able to log results?

Comment: @phpdroid - no I don't have logs , this is the first App I'm writing

Answer (score 3):

All the UI rendering should be done on main thread, you can use view handler to do that

```
v.post(new Runnable(){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside the thread",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
});
```

Comment: where to add this? ,

Answer (score 3):

This will execute on UI thread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside the thread",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: where to add this?

Comment: replace your toast with this code inside  run method in Thread

Comment: didn't work -  I don't see nothing. and in the debug mode I can see it skip this and go to on

Comment: put my code above this line in your code clientSocket.close();

Comment: I did , didn't work - I have edit the question , and you can see how it's look now . maybe I write it wrong?

Comment: you placed code at right place,you can  also check through debugging by setting breakpoints

Comment: when I debug and make a break point here - "mBufferIn.close();" after that he jsut skip the "runOnUiThread" part

Comment: did you put breakpoint inside runOnUiThreadtoast in toast too?

Comment: yes , he enter the "runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { "  and after this line he jump to    clientSocket.close(); , no Execption been catch

Answer (score 2):

Your toast is coming from a background thread, it needs to be executed on the main/UI thread

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside the thread",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: where do I need to add this?

Comment: didn't put add it nowhere yet. this is why I'm asking :-)

Comment: and also I need the text will be the ServerReply string - so do I need to cahnge somethig else?

Answer (score 1):

`Toast` can't be run on other than the UI thread, you can use

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           //see why this is not working - can;t see the toast
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside the thread",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: nope , doesn't work , in Debug I can see it skipp this part

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You have to write toast in UI thread. like blow

```
// you can write toast in UI thread like this
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside the thread",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

**2)** You have to make sure `intentData.length()` is not 0 ( if your intentData is empty then your thread will never execute, be sure about that.)

```
if (intentData.length() > 0) {...}
```

**3)** And also make sure your code not given any exception before showing your toast message [handle your exception in catch block like following]

```
catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Exception","your exception is "+e.toString());
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: when it's 0 - meaning no QR code is been scan. and this part is working.   and I did shwat you suggested(you can see on the Post)  - didn't work .

Comment: @Afik_Android see my updated answer, especially `No. #3`.
if 1 and 2 are okay then I think your code caught an exception before showing toast message.

Comment: Nothing , I don't get any exception . it just skip the "runOnUiThread" part